# Asking my supervisor to be frank and give feedback

Tags: advisor, supervision, feedback

I am doing my PhD in the Britain and I've got a lovely supervisor which is like a friend for me. I want to ask her to give me direct feedback and tell me directly if I am doing bullshit or about any other thing that she thinks I am not good and need to improve (forexample if the way I send email is not very natural in the sense of language and ...). I want to say:

I would like to ask you to give me direct feedback on anything that you think I may need to improve. I won't be offended because I know your intention and I know you want me to be the best. I would be very happy to receive comment because I know that's what makes me improve.

Is it good or not? Is there as better way of saying that?

Comment: Is there a reason you believe your supervisor isn’t giving you honest feedback?

Comment: I think she does give feedback on some part of my work, but not on every aspect. And the feedbacks are indirect

Comment: What do you mean with "indirect"? Have you specifically asked about the aspects that interest you?

Comment: Are you both from the UK? There are cultural differences in the way people give and expect feedback.

Comment: No, I am not from the UK. There might be. @Mark

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are overthinking this. You say she is like a friend. Neither a friend, nor an advisor, has any incentive to lead you into traps. Accept it if she praises your work. Perhaps you are on the right track after all.

But we can all improve at the margins, at least. If you have specific doubts about particular things that you do, or write, ask about just those things and listen to the answers. Perhaps there are suggestions for improvement in there that aren't criticisms, but just pointers to better ways to do or say things.

But, your note almost sounds like you are soliciting negative feedback.

I'm pretty sure that if a friend and advisor saw you going down the wrong road you would be told that. Otherwise she is wasting her own time as well as yours. That doesn't seem like a reasonable action for an advisor.

After all, if you finish and go on to a brilliant career it reflects well on her also. Relax.

Answer (score 1):

Many people are not good in giving feedback. Often, academica have never learned management skills like giving feedback. Some people think they are "mean" if they give negative things, some people feel they are being "picky" if they list small things (even if the other person would be interested in small things also).

From dealing with students (giving feedback on each other's talks), my feeling is that more specific questions like "List 3 things that could be improved" are more often answered then "What could be improved?". Also, there tend to be more and better responses when the feedback is written.
So, I would look in the Internet for a good feeback sheet which applies to your situation. Or create one yourself. Ask the supervisor if they would fill it out since it would help you (some academics hate it when they have to fill out yet another sheet of paper). Ask specifically for comments (not only for "grades" which do not tell much about how you could improve). Try to include only important questions as you do not want to annoy her.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I would make a blanket request for feedback on everything. It sounds not only like an invitation for negative feedback, as Buffy mentioned, but also an invitation to change the dynamics of your relationship, to a more critical one. I think it would also be hard for an advisor to know how to address such a general request - like how much feedback is this student looking for, where does the feedback stop?

My own suggestion is that if you wish to receive more candid feedback from her, maybe make that request when it comes to specific things. For example, if you have a manuscript draft or want to do a mock job interview or a dry run of a presentation - these would be good things to get feedback on and would be appropriate to ask her to not hold back regarding her critiques. For smaller things though, I think it might be a bit much for her and is heading into babysitting territory, as there are some things you just need to learn and figure out yourself through trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other answers that asking for "negative feedback on anything at all, please, hit me" isn't the way to go.

But what you can do is say "hey, I have to submit this essay and I'm nervous about it, I'm afraid I'll overlook something big. Could you have a look at it and see if you can shoot any holes in it that I can fix before submitting?"

Also, read about [Impostor Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impostor_syndrome). It's very common in academia, take a look at yourself and consider if any of this might apply to you?